# Export GridView To CSV file using streamwritter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, csv, datagridview

I am writing a program and am stuck. I wanted to be able to edit a datagrid with in a opened program and click a button to save and update the CSV file that the datagrid is filled with.

I know this is possible but need help with how to get this working with my code:

```
       private void GridView(List<string[]> parsedData)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder(parsedData[0][i]);
                sb.Replace('_', ' ');
                sb.Replace("\"", "");
                dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name = sb.ToString();
            }

            foreach (string[] row in parsedData)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[0]);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<string[]> parsedData = read(@"c:\users\dick\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\file.csv", ',');

            GridView(parsedData);

        }



        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string[]> parsedData = read(@"c:\users\dick\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Alteredfile.csv", ';');

            GridView(parsedData);

        }



        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                sb.Append(dataGridView1.Columns[k].HeaderText + ',');
            }
            sb.Append("\r\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int K = 0; K < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; K++)
                {
                    sb.Append(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[K].ErrorText + ',');
                }
                sb.Append("\r\n");
            }

            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\users\dick\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Alteredfile.csv"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }

    }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it right now, but this line is wrong:

```
 sb.Append(dataGridView1.Columns[k].HeaderText + ',');
```

You should do something like this to get the strings of the grid:

```
(string)dataGridView1.Rows[x].Columns[k].value
```

or

```
(string[])dataGridView1.Rows[x].value
```